# How to calculate EV or optimize a value when there is a chance of getting a 0x multiplier

Tags: probability, statistics

I play this game with some friends that has a supposed "last ditch effort" gambling system

You take an item with value X and every time you click on a button it multiplies that value by a randomly determined multiplier from the following

0.03 chance 10x multiplier

0.11 chance 3x multiplier

0.27 chance 2x multiplier

0.5 chance 0.5x multiplier

0.09 chance 0x multiplier

I quickly calculated out an EV of 1.42 but I realized that after hitting 0 you could obviously never get back up. So now I've been racking my brain trying to figure out the best approach to this problem

I thought maybe I could optimize profit by going to a exact amount of guesses, but if I was losing money at that point maybe I should have kept going for the rare comeback?

So I thought maybe have a profit goal and continue to bet until I 0 out or reach that goal. obviously the safest version of that number would be (original value)+1 but I would rather the maximum value in which the chance for success is over 50% that way over many items I would be likely to make a profit.

If my approach is completely incorrect, or there is an easier way of looking at this that works too :)

EDIT: I should probably include that anecdotally the button is very much profitable

Comment: You haven’t defined what you’re trying to achieve. You seem to imply two goals, maximizing an expected value and maxiziming the probability of making a profit. In this game, those are conflicting goals: The longer you play, the higher the expected value and the lower the probability that you make a profit. For there to be a well-defined mathematical question, you need to specify what you’re trying to optimize.

Comment: This game is similar to the one in the so-called [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox). You can find a number of considerations in that article that also apply to your game.